# Getting the file extension without knowing it's name

Tags: javascript, file

I need to know if there is a way to retrieve the **real** file extension without parse the filename.

In my code I split the file using the function `split(filename, ".")` then i get the last element of the array that the function returns.

Now, if I create a `.pdf` file called, for example `test_file.pdf`, the previous method works perfectly, but if i rename my file to `test_file`(without extension) I cannot retrieve the extension even if I know that the file is a PDF.

For example, if i rename test_file.pdf to text_file.jpg how can I recognize that the file is still a pdf and not an image file with .jpg extension?

I would like to know if there is a way to obtain this information, maybe using file metadata or other information related to the file.

I'm looking for a Javascript solution because I have to check the extension when I upload the file using a form (client side) but even a Java solution could be fine, can you help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get real file extension -Java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091014/get-real-file-extension-java-code)

Comment: It sounds like you're interested in the type of content in the file, regardless of the filename. Your question is currently confusing when you talk about the "file extension" because that *is* part of the filename.

Comment: I think he means (if I and we understood him correctly) that if he uses a proper format then the file is locatable, but searching for "test_file" doesn't net any result even though it should. All I could say OP is see what output your splitter does and see if it even saves the test_file name.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this post and the marked answer: [Get real file extension -Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091014/get-real-file-extension-java-code)

I guess it's just what you need.

Comment: A link to another SO question or answer does not make a good answer in itself. Next time, you should flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I'm new to this. Didn't know how to flag as a duplicate :O