# How can I get the actual file extension in Java

Tags: java, mime-types, file-extension

I know I can get this by doing this

```
String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension("/path/to/file/foo.txt");
```

But what if someone tries to upload a **foo.exe** file by just changing the extension type to **foo.doc**. Is there any way through which I can get the actual extension type without reading the content of file

Comment: MIME types, magic number headers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
File file = new File("filename.asgdsag");
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
```

From this post : [Get real file extension -Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091014/get-real-file-extension-java-code)

---

Also using java7, you should check out this :

```
public static String probeContentType(Path path)
                           throws IOException
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, let me try this. I tried to find it on stackoverflow, But didn't found that

Comment: Do not post the code from the duplicate, instead, mark the post as duplicate and link to the duplicated item.

Comment: Alright Kevin, my bad, kinda new around here

Comment: Note you're not getting downvotes - only because you're new :)

Comment: I tried this but I got mimeType as null in that case. I am using mulipartFile.

Comment: And also I tried ProbeContentType, but it is only giving me the real type of extension. Is there any way ??