# How to get the real extension type of Multipart file

Tags: java, file, mime-types

I have  checked answer here, but here first they are saving it to some place and then reading it's stream and trying to check Mime type of that file

[Get real file extension -Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091014/get-real-file-extension-java-code)

But I want to know the file type before even saving it to the hard disk or at some place.

I know I can do it in these 2 more ways

```
File savedFile = new File(fileHandler.createTodayFolder(fileLocation) + "/" + name);
            Path path = Paths.get(file.get);
            Tika tika = new Tika();
            String checkType = tika.detect(path.toFile());
```

and

```
          Path path = Paths.get(savedFile.getPath());
          Files.probeContentType(path)
```

But in these both cases they are using somefile which is already at some location in hard disk. 
I want code something like this

```
  public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> importResume(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

     if (file!=DESIRED_TYPE)
     {
       return Exception;
     }
}
```

Is there any way of doing this ???

Comment: You need to start streaming it (reading it) otherwise you can't check MIME.

Comment: @PetterFriberg- So what I am doing is correct or not ??

Comment: Its arrving in a stream I suppose, before saving to the hd check the stream for MIME type.... if ok you save otherwise not...

Comment: @PetterFriberg- It is coming as a multipart file, currently I am saving it as file and then checking it's type which is wrong for security purposes. searching ways to streaming it(reading it).

Comment: @VipulJain did u find any solution??

Answer (score 86):

For me, the cleanest solution:

using FilenameUtils of org.apache.commons.io:

```
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
```

Comment: Note from the documentation: The `IllegalArgumentException` is possible on Windows. This method used to have a hidden problem for names like "foo.exe:bar.txt". In this case, the name wouldn't be the name of a file, but the identifier of an alternate data stream (bar.txt) on the file foo.exe. The method used to return ".txt" here, which would be misleading. Commons IO 2.7, and later versions, are throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` for names like this.

Comment: CAUTION! This methods just checks the file extension of the file path. It doesn't actually check the file bytes which may be different from the extension.

Answer (score 25):

You can use Tika https://tika.apache.org/

```
//file is a MultipartFile    
if(!file.isEmpty)
{
  Tika tika = new Tika();
  String detectedType = tika.detect(file.getBytes());
  System.out.println(detectedType);
}
```

This should get you the mimetype without saving the file

Comment: This works like a charm. Even after renaming the files they detect original file type. Thanks :)

Comment: @Veesta This method return wrong mimetype for a multipart file

Answer (score 17):

Given the String `filename`, you can do:

```
filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

Comment: may be but he needs to access this from Multipartfile and not String as he has given in the eg. controller

Comment: @valik to get the file name, just use `file.getOriginalFilename()`

Answer (score 16):

You can map the mimetype to a existing extension by making a map...

You can use apache.mime.types for create one like it's done here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/MapfileextensionstoMIMEtypesBasedontheApachemimetypesfile.htm

```
public class MimeTypes {

  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_ANDREW_INSET  = "application/andrew-inset";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_JSON      = "application/json";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_ZIP       = "application/zip";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_GZIP      = "application/x-gzip";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_TGZ       = "application/tgz";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_MSWORD      = "application/msword";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_POSTSCRIPT    = "application/postscript";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_PDF       = "application/pdf";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_JNLP      = "application/jnlp";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_MAC_BINHEX40  = "application/mac-binhex40";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_MAC_COMPACTPRO  = "application/mac-compactpro";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_MATHML_XML    = "application/mathml+xml";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM  = "application/octet-stream";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_ODA       = "application/oda";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_RDF_XML     = "application/rdf+xml";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_JAVA_ARCHIVE  = "application/java-archive";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_RDF_SMIL    = "application/smil";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_SRGS      = "application/srgs";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_SRGS_XML    = "application/srgs+xml";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_VND_MIF     = "application/vnd.mif";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_VND_MSEXCEL   = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_VND_MSPOWERPOINT= "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_VND_RNREALMEDIA = "application/vnd.rn-realmedia";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_BCPIO     = "application/x-bcpio";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_CDLINK    = "application/x-cdlink";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_CHESS_PGN   = "application/x-chess-pgn";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_CPIO      = "application/x-cpio";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_CSH     = "application/x-csh";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_DIRECTOR    = "application/x-director";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_DVI     = "application/x-dvi";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_FUTURESPLASH  = "application/x-futuresplash";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_GTAR      = "application/x-gtar";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_HDF     = "application/x-hdf";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_JAVASCRIPT  = "application/x-javascript";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_KOAN      = "application/x-koan";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_LATEX     = "application/x-latex";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_NETCDF    = "application/x-netcdf";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_OGG     = "application/x-ogg";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_SH      = "application/x-sh";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_SHAR      = "application/x-shar";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_SHOCKWAVE_FLASH = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_STUFFIT     = "application/x-stuffit";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_SV4CPIO     = "application/x-sv4cpio";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_SV4CRC    = "application/x-sv4crc";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_TAR       = "application/x-tar";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_RAR_COMPRESSED= "application/x-rar-compressed";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_TCL       = "application/x-tcl";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_TEX       = "application/x-tex";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_TEXINFO   = "application/x-texinfo";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_TROFF     = "application/x-troff";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_TROFF_MAN   = "application/x-troff-man";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_TROFF_ME    = "application/x-troff-me";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_TROFF_MS    = "application/x-troff-ms";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_USTAR     = "application/x-ustar";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_X_WAIS_SOURCE = "application/x-wais-source";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_VND_MOZZILLA_XUL_XML = "application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_XHTML_XML     = "application/xhtml+xml";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_XSLT_XML    = "application/xslt+xml";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_XML       = "application/xml";
  public static final String MIME_APPLICATION_XML_DTD     = "application/xml-dtd";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_BMP         = "image/bmp";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_CGM         = "image/cgm";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_GIF         = "image/gif";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_IEF         = "image/ief";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_JPEG          = "image/jpeg";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_TIFF          = "image/tiff";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_PNG         = "image/png";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_SVG_XML       = "image/svg+xml";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_VND_DJVU        = "image/vnd.djvu";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_WAP_WBMP        = "image/vnd.wap.wbmp";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_X_CMU_RASTER      = "image/x-cmu-raster";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_X_ICON        = "image/x-icon";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_X_PORTABLE_ANYMAP   = "image/x-portable-anymap";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_X_PORTABLE_BITMAP   = "image/x-portable-bitmap";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_X_PORTABLE_GRAYMAP  = "image/x-portable-graymap";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_X_PORTABLE_PIXMAP   = "image/x-portable-pixmap";
  public static final String MIME_IMAGE_X_RGB         = "image/x-rgb";
  public static final String MIME_AUDIO_BASIC         = "audio/basic";
  public static final String MIME_AUDIO_MIDI          = "audio/midi";
  public static final String MIME_AUDIO_MPEG          = "audio/mpeg";
  public static final String MIME_AUDIO_X_AIFF        = "audio/x-aiff";
  public static final String MIME_AUDIO_X_MPEGURL       = "audio/x-mpegurl";
  public static final String MIME_AUDIO_X_PN_REALAUDIO    = "audio/x-pn-realaudio";
  public static final String MIME_AUDIO_X_WAV         = "audio/x-wav";
  public static final String MIME_CHEMICAL_X_PDB        = "chemical/x-pdb";
  public static final String MIME_CHEMICAL_X_XYZ        = "chemical/x-xyz";
  public static final String MIME_MODEL_IGES          = "model/iges";
  public static final String MIME_MODEL_MESH          = "model/mesh";
  public static final String MIME_MODEL_VRLM          = "model/vrml";
  public static final String MIME_TEXT_PLAIN          = "text/plain";
  public static final String MIME_TEXT_RICHTEXT       = "text/richtext";
  public static final String MIME_TEXT_RTF          = "text/rtf";
  public static final String MIME_TEXT_HTML         = "text/html";
  public static final String MIME_TEXT_CALENDAR       = "text/calendar";
  public static final String MIME_TEXT_CSS          = "text/css";
  public static final String MIME_TEXT_SGML         = "text/sgml";
  public static final String MIME_TEXT_TAB_SEPARATED_VALUES = "text/tab-separated-values";
  public static final String MIME_TEXT_VND_WAP_XML      = "text/vnd.wap.wml";
  public static final String MIME_TEXT_VND_WAP_WMLSCRIPT    = "text/vnd.wap.wmlscript";
  public static final String MIME_TEXT_X_SETEXT       = "text/x-setext";
  public static final String MIME_TEXT_X_COMPONENT      = "text/x-component";
  public static final String MIME_VIDEO_QUICKTIME       = "video/quicktime";
  public static final String MIME_VIDEO_MPEG          = "video/mpeg";
  public static final String MIME_VIDEO_VND_MPEGURL     = "video/vnd.mpegurl";
  public static final String MIME_VIDEO_X_MSVIDEO       = "video/x-msvideo";
  public static final String MIME_VIDEO_X_MS_WMV        = "video/x-ms-wmv";
  public static final String MIME_VIDEO_X_SGI_MOVIE     = "video/x-sgi-movie";
  public static final String MIME_X_CONFERENCE_X_COOLTALK   = "x-conference/x-cooltalk";

  private static HashMap<String, String> mimeTypeMapping;

  static {
    mimeTypeMapping = new HashMap<String, String>(200) {
      private void put1(String key, String value) {
        if (put(key, value) != null) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicated extension: " + key);
        }
      }
      {
      put1("xul", MIME_APPLICATION_VND_MOZZILLA_XUL_XML);
      put1("json", MIME_APPLICATION_JSON);
      put1("ice", MIME_X_CONFERENCE_X_COOLTALK);
      put1("movie", MIME_VIDEO_X_SGI_MOVIE);
      put1("avi", MIME_VIDEO_X_MSVIDEO);
      put1("wmv", MIME_VIDEO_X_MS_WMV);
      put1("m4u", MIME_VIDEO_VND_MPEGURL);
      put1("mxu", MIME_VIDEO_VND_MPEGURL);
      put1("htc", MIME_TEXT_X_COMPONENT);
      put1("etx", MIME_TEXT_X_SETEXT);
      put1("wmls", MIME_TEXT_VND_WAP_WMLSCRIPT);
      put1("wml", MIME_TEXT_VND_WAP_XML);
      put1("tsv", MIME_TEXT_TAB_SEPARATED_VALUES);
      put1("sgm", MIME_TEXT_SGML);
      put1("sgml", MIME_TEXT_SGML);
      put1("css", MIME_TEXT_CSS);
      put1("ifb", MIME_TEXT_CALENDAR);
      put1("ics", MIME_TEXT_CALENDAR);
      put1("wrl", MIME_MODEL_VRLM);
      put1("vrlm", MIME_MODEL_VRLM);
      put1("silo", MIME_MODEL_MESH);
      put1("mesh", MIME_MODEL_MESH);
      put1("msh", MIME_MODEL_MESH);
      put1("iges", MIME_MODEL_IGES);
      put1("igs", MIME_MODEL_IGES);
      put1("rgb", MIME_IMAGE_X_RGB);
      put1("ppm", MIME_IMAGE_X_PORTABLE_PIXMAP);
      put1("pgm", MIME_IMAGE_X_PORTABLE_GRAYMAP);
      put1("pbm", MIME_IMAGE_X_PORTABLE_BITMAP);
      put1("pnm", MIME_IMAGE_X_PORTABLE_ANYMAP);
      put1("ico", MIME_IMAGE_X_ICON);
      put1("ras", MIME_IMAGE_X_CMU_RASTER);
      put1("wbmp", MIME_IMAGE_WAP_WBMP);
      put1("djv", MIME_IMAGE_VND_DJVU);
      put1("djvu", MIME_IMAGE_VND_DJVU);
      put1("svg", MIME_IMAGE_SVG_XML);
      put1("ief", MIME_IMAGE_IEF);
      put1("cgm", MIME_IMAGE_CGM);
      put1("bmp", MIME_IMAGE_BMP);
      put1("xyz", MIME_CHEMICAL_X_XYZ);
      put1("pdb", MIME_CHEMICAL_X_PDB);
      put1("ra", MIME_AUDIO_X_PN_REALAUDIO);
      put1("ram", MIME_AUDIO_X_PN_REALAUDIO);
      put1("m3u", MIME_AUDIO_X_MPEGURL);
      put1("aifc", MIME_AUDIO_X_AIFF);
      put1("aif", MIME_AUDIO_X_AIFF);
      put1("aiff", MIME_AUDIO_X_AIFF);
      put1("mp3", MIME_AUDIO_MPEG);
      put1("mp2", MIME_AUDIO_MPEG);
      put1("mp1", MIME_AUDIO_MPEG);
      put1("mpga", MIME_AUDIO_MPEG);
      put1("kar", MIME_AUDIO_MIDI);
      put1("mid", MIME_AUDIO_MIDI);
      put1("midi", MIME_AUDIO_MIDI);
      put1("dtd", MIME_APPLICATION_XML_DTD);
      put1("xsl", MIME_APPLICATION_XML);
      put1("xml", MIME_APPLICATION_XML);
      put1("xslt", MIME_APPLICATION_XSLT_XML);
      put1("xht", MIME_APPLICATION_XHTML_XML);
      put1("xhtml", MIME_APPLICATION_XHTML_XML);
      put1("src", MIME_APPLICATION_X_WAIS_SOURCE);
      put1("ustar", MIME_APPLICATION_X_USTAR);
      put1("ms", MIME_APPLICATION_X_TROFF_MS);
      put1("me", MIME_APPLICATION_X_TROFF_ME);
      put1("man", MIME_APPLICATION_X_TROFF_MAN);
      put1("roff", MIME_APPLICATION_X_TROFF);
      put1("tr", MIME_APPLICATION_X_TROFF);
      put1("t", MIME_APPLICATION_X_TROFF);
      put1("texi", MIME_APPLICATION_X_TEXINFO);
      put1("texinfo", MIME_APPLICATION_X_TEXINFO);
      put1("tex", MIME_APPLICATION_X_TEX);
      put1("tcl", MIME_APPLICATION_X_TCL);
      put1("sv4crc", MIME_APPLICATION_X_SV4CRC);
      put1("sv4cpio", MIME_APPLICATION_X_SV4CPIO);
      put1("sit", MIME_APPLICATION_X_STUFFIT);
      put1("swf", MIME_APPLICATION_X_SHOCKWAVE_FLASH);
      put1("shar", MIME_APPLICATION_X_SHAR);
      put1("sh", MIME_APPLICATION_X_SH);
      put1("cdf", MIME_APPLICATION_X_NETCDF);
      put1("nc", MIME_APPLICATION_X_NETCDF);
      put1("latex", MIME_APPLICATION_X_LATEX);
      put1("skm", MIME_APPLICATION_X_KOAN);
      put1("skt", MIME_APPLICATION_X_KOAN);
      put1("skd", MIME_APPLICATION_X_KOAN);
      put1("skp", MIME_APPLICATION_X_KOAN);
      put1("js", MIME_APPLICATION_X_JAVASCRIPT);
      put1("hdf", MIME_APPLICATION_X_HDF);
      put1("gtar", MIME_APPLICATION_X_GTAR);
      put1("spl", MIME_APPLICATION_X_FUTURESPLASH);
      put1("dvi", MIME_APPLICATION_X_DVI);
      put1("dxr", MIME_APPLICATION_X_DIRECTOR);
      put1("dir", MIME_APPLICATION_X_DIRECTOR);
      put1("dcr", MIME_APPLICATION_X_DIRECTOR);
      put1("csh", MIME_APPLICATION_X_CSH);
      put1("cpio", MIME_APPLICATION_X_CPIO);
      put1("pgn", MIME_APPLICATION_X_CHESS_PGN);
      put1("vcd", MIME_APPLICATION_X_CDLINK);
      put1("bcpio", MIME_APPLICATION_X_BCPIO);
      put1("rm", MIME_APPLICATION_VND_RNREALMEDIA);
      put1("ppt", MIME_APPLICATION_VND_MSPOWERPOINT);
      put1("mif", MIME_APPLICATION_VND_MIF);
      put1("grxml", MIME_APPLICATION_SRGS_XML);
      put1("gram", MIME_APPLICATION_SRGS);
      put1("smil", MIME_APPLICATION_RDF_SMIL);
      put1("smi", MIME_APPLICATION_RDF_SMIL);
      put1("rdf", MIME_APPLICATION_RDF_XML);
      put1("ogg", MIME_APPLICATION_X_OGG);
      put1("oda", MIME_APPLICATION_ODA);
      put1("dmg", MIME_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
      put1("lzh", MIME_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
      put1("so", MIME_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
      put1("lha", MIME_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
      put1("dms", MIME_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
      put1("bin", MIME_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
      put1("mathml", MIME_APPLICATION_MATHML_XML);
      put1("cpt", MIME_APPLICATION_MAC_COMPACTPRO);
      put1("hqx", MIME_APPLICATION_MAC_BINHEX40);
      put1("jnlp", MIME_APPLICATION_JNLP);
      put1("ez", MIME_APPLICATION_ANDREW_INSET);
      put1("txt", MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
      put1("ini", MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
      put1("c", MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
      put1("h", MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
      put1("cpp", MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
      put1("cxx", MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
      put1("cc", MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
      put1("chh", MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
      put1("java", MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
      put1("csv", MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
      put1("bat", MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
      put1("cmd", MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
      put1("asc", MIME_TEXT_PLAIN);
      put1("rtf", MIME_TEXT_RTF);
      put1("rtx", MIME_TEXT_RICHTEXT);
      put1("html", MIME_TEXT_HTML);
      put1("htm", MIME_TEXT_HTML);
      put1("zip", MIME_APPLICATION_ZIP);
      put1("rar", MIME_APPLICATION_X_RAR_COMPRESSED);
      put1("gzip", MIME_APPLICATION_X_GZIP);
      put1("gz", MIME_APPLICATION_X_GZIP);
      put1("tgz", MIME_APPLICATION_TGZ);
      put1("tar", MIME_APPLICATION_X_TAR);
      put1("gif", MIME_IMAGE_GIF);
      put1("jpeg", MIME_IMAGE_JPEG);
      put1("jpg", MIME_IMAGE_JPEG);
      put1("jpe", MIME_IMAGE_JPEG);
      put1("tiff", MIME_IMAGE_TIFF);
      put1("tif", MIME_IMAGE_TIFF);
      put1("png", MIME_IMAGE_PNG);
      put1("au", MIME_AUDIO_BASIC);
      put1("snd", MIME_AUDIO_BASIC);
      put1("wav", MIME_AUDIO_X_WAV);
      put1("mov", MIME_VIDEO_QUICKTIME);
      put1("qt", MIME_VIDEO_QUICKTIME);
      put1("mpeg", MIME_VIDEO_MPEG);
      put1("mpg", MIME_VIDEO_MPEG);
      put1("mpe", MIME_VIDEO_MPEG);
      put1("abs", MIME_VIDEO_MPEG);
      put1("doc", MIME_APPLICATION_MSWORD);
      put1("xls", MIME_APPLICATION_VND_MSEXCEL);
      put1("eps", MIME_APPLICATION_POSTSCRIPT);
      put1("ai", MIME_APPLICATION_POSTSCRIPT);
      put1("ps", MIME_APPLICATION_POSTSCRIPT);
      put1("pdf", MIME_APPLICATION_PDF);
      put1("exe", MIME_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
      put1("dll", MIME_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
      put1("class", MIME_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
      put1("jar", MIME_APPLICATION_JAVA_ARCHIVE);
    }};
      }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(mimeTypeMapping.size());
  }

  /**
   * Registers MIME type for provided extension. Existing extension type will be overriden.
   */
  public static void registerMimeType(String ext, String mimeType) {
    mimeTypeMapping.put(ext, mimeType);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the corresponding MIME type to the given extension.
   * If no MIME type was found it returns 'application/octet-stream' type.
   */
  public static String getMimeType(String ext) {
    String mimeType = lookupMimeType(ext);
    if (mimeType == null) {
      mimeType = MIME_APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM;
    }
    return mimeType;
  }

  /**
   * Simply returns MIME type or <code>null</code> if no type is found.
   */
  public static String lookupMimeType(String ext) {
    return mimeTypeMapping.get(ext.toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

That way you could obtain the extension from the content-type...

Answer (score 11):

To get the file extension You could do:

```
multipartFile.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")[1];
```

The name You get with:

```
 multipartFile.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")[0];
```

What if the user upload a executable file with .doc extension? You could get the content type:

```
multipartFile.getContentType();
```

This will return a MIME type string.
To get the correct file extension you could search the file name string for the last dot and then split it at this position.

Comment: But what if someone uploads a executable file and names it some doc file, then this will not work I think. Or if someone upload a file with 2 extension then also it will not work

Comment: This solution will not work if you have file name with dot ,  like - "Screen Shot 2017-03-03 at 6.56.04 PM.png".

Comment: Read carefully the answer: "[...] you could search the file name string for the last dot [...]"

Answer (score 9):

you can use `org.springframework.util.StringUtils` :

```
String extension = StringUtils.getFilenameExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(inputFile.getOriginalFilename());
System.out.println("File Extension "+extension);
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue with splitting on . and taking the last part (not the 2nd),

To get Extension

```
          String[] fileFrags = file.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")
          String extension = fileFrags[fileFrags.length-1]
```

To get the name

```
          String fileName  = file.substring(0,file.lenghth()-fileFrags[fileFrags-1].length()-1)
```

Comment: This solution verifies only file extension which is not directly connected with mime type (i.e. someone uploaded .exe file with .doc extension)

Comment: This is an invalid way of checking file type and should be avoided at all cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can check file extension in this way:

```
 if (file.getContentType() == null
        || !file.getContentType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Wrong extension!");
    }
```