# Android: Is it possible to check the file is an apk file if no extension supplied

Tags: android, file, apk, file-extension

I am writing an application which will upload a file to another device. I have to restrict how the file type to be shared to another device. I can check the file extension but is there a safer way to check the file is an apk or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get real file extension -Java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091014/get-real-file-extension-java-code)

Comment: If you think my answer covers what you were looking for, then can you set it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. The android apk file is a [zip archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package).

So you can check if the file is a zip file, and confirm that the `classes.dex` and `AndroidManifest.xml` files exist.

Comment: Do you know how to get into the file to check it programmatically?

Comment: I found the solution by using JarFile class and lookup the entry of the manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Considering the idea of **Passer by**, here is a method that checks if a file is a valid APK

```
       public static boolean isAPK(File file) {
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            ZipInputStream zipIs = null;
            ZipEntry zEntry = null;
            String dexFile = "classes.dex";
            String manifestFile = "AndroidManifest.xml";
            boolean hasDex = false;
            boolean hasManifest = false;

            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                zipIs = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
                while ((zEntry = zipIs.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                    if (zEntry.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(dexFile)) {
                        hasDex = true;
                    } else if (zEntry.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(manifestFile)) {
                        hasManifest = true;
                    }
                    if (hasDex && hasManifest) {
                        zipIs.close();
                        fis.close();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                zipIs.close();
                fis.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible doing this class:

```
new MimeTypeMap()
```

according to the Android documentation should give the right result:

`Two-way map that maps MIME-types to file extensions and vice versa.`

Comment: This relies on the file extension which is what the original question is trying to avoid - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html#getContentType(java.io.File)

Comment: :/ ... you sure ... this should check the MIME type ... not the ext

Comment: Yes if the documentation is correct, it's going by a map of file extensions which it compares against, besides `MimetypesFileTypeMap` isn't available in the Android SDK.

Comment: sorry .... I corrected my answer to using `MimeTypeMap` which is a `android.webkit` that according to the documentation should do the job

Comment: `MimeTypeMap` Two-way map that maps MIME-types to file extensions and vice versa.

Comment: My point is [these](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html) (If you look at the public methods) require you to provide a file extension. The second closest thing is [URLConnection#guessContentTypeFromStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream(java.io.InputStream)) which will probably return zip archive or `application/octet-stream` as apks don't have any special byte headers.

Comment: I see what you mean ... thank you for clarifying that to me

Comment: how about using this to our advantage !?

Comment: I have tried using URLConnection.GuessContentTypeFromStream on a pdf file but returning null. The file i passing  into the stream is : /storage/emulated/0/Download/file.pdf