# How to check whether the uploaded file is XLS file or not?

Tags: java, javascript, html, file-upload

I have a file uploader module. The UI is created using simple HTML and Javascript.
Server side I am using Java code. I want to check the type of the uploaded file.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java

Comment: In server side or client side??

Comment: @Rahul:I want to check the file type in Server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files don't really have types.  The best you can do would be to attempt to load the file as an XLS.

- If the load succeeds, the file is most likely an XLS.
- If the load fails, the file is either an invalid/malformed XLS, or not an XLS at all.

You can also look at the uploaded file name or the content type, but neither of these is definitive; i.e. they might *say* that the file is an XLS when it is something completely different.