# Is there any method to deduct content type from File

Tags: java, file, mime-types, mime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting A File's Mime Type In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java)

have a File, is there a way to deduct its content type like application/xml etc?

Answer (score 1):

```
new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(new File("yourFile"));
```

---

**See Also**

- [getContentType(File f)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html#getContentType%28java.io.File%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try [jMimeMagic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/) and [Mime Type Detection Utility](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/)

Taken from: [How to detect files type](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-detect-file-type)