# Is there a helper function to find a mime type corresponding to an extension

Tags: java, servlets, mime-types

Mime types corresponding to an extension is available over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp). We currently have the following code to translate this for the most commonly used extension types.

```
     String getContentType(String extension) {
        if (extension.equals("png") || extension.equals("gif")
                || extension.equals("ico") || extension.equals("tiff")) {
            contentType = "image/" + extension;
        } else if (extension.equals("jpg") || extension.equals("jpeg")) {
            contentType = "image/jpeg";
        } 
        ........
     }
```

But is there a function in a open source library which provides this complete mapping?

Comment: Yes it seems there are several ways to get that. Please visit [this page](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java