# Azure Storage: How to check if a blob represents a valid image

Tags: image, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I provide users with a SAS token to upload blobs. I'd like to check whether the blobs represent a valid image or not. How can I do this? In the SAS token, I make sure the blob name ends with a jpeg extension, but this does not mean the users upload an image since everything is uploaded as a byte stream.

Answer (score 1):

This is **Not** possible as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120456/how-to-get-file-type-extension-from-byte-blob). Perhaps, the better way to validate is at the front end when the user tries to upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an Azure Function that will be triggered every time a new blob is uploaded. And in that function you can validate if the blob is a valid image file, if it is not then you can delete it or send an email to uploader.