# Getting the correct MIME type of a file in Java

Tags: java, mime-types

I read that Files.probeContentType(path) can be used to get the file type of a file without relying on file extensions. However in my case, if I remove the file type, the function returns the file type "null". If I attach the correct extension, then I get the type as "image/jpeg". Can anyone what is going on here or is my understanding of probeContentType not correct? I'm expecting it to return "image/jpeg" irrespective of the fact that it has file extension or not.

This is the case where I deliberately removed the extension from the file "Nature.jpg":

[image]

**Update**
Using org.apache.tika (v2.4)

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
String myType = tika.detect(filePath);
```

If the file extension is not present I get the filetype as "application/octet-stream". The image is originally jpeg so I was expecting it to detect it as an image.

Comment: Do any of these options (beside Tika) work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120456/how-to-get-file-type-extension-from-byte-blob

Answer (score 1):

While it might not rely on the file extension in all implementations, it might use it in others. According to Oracle - "The implementation of this method is highly platform specific and is not infallible."

"The means by which a file type detector determines the file type is highly implementation specific. A simple implementation might examine the file extension (a convention used in some platforms) and map it to a file type. In other cases, the file type may be stored as a file attribute or the bytes in a file may be examined to guess its file type." - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html

You can try Apache Tika as an alternative, I've had good experiences with it - https://tika.apache.org/

Comment: I see. Can you elaboate if Apache Tika can be installed on Windows? Also, is this OS dependent and not a package I can install in SpringBoot?

Comment: @Ashar You can use it with spring. You can add it as a maven/gradle dependency and use it in any Java project

Comment: @rhowll I tried using it but got an exception. Added it as an update to the post. Pleas have a look.

Comment: @Ashar which version of Tiki are you using? As it's registering a component via SPI, you need to make sure the version you've selected matches the java runtime. Your updated question says v0.7, but v2.4.x is the latest version?

Comment: @slindenau I have updated the post. Unfortunately it still wasn't able to cater to my requriement.