# How to extract file extension from byte array

Tags: java, sql, arrays, mime-types

I've got bytes array in database.

How to extract file extension (mime/type) from byte array in java?

Comment: `byte array` is an array of bytes and nothing more. If you have a `byte array` - you can't say what's stored there. You can try guessing by the contents of the byte array, but it will be nothing more but guessing.

Comment: I don't think so, I can do it with MagicMatch class, but for this I need to import external jar. I'm seeking for something else.

byte[] data = ...
MagicMatch match = Magic.getMagicMatch(data);
String mimeType = match.getMimeType();

Comment: What I meant to say - there is no mimetype saved within a byte array anywhere (except for some datatypes which support it). For example if you have a `Hello World.txt` file written to byte array, you would have 11 bytes in it: `H,e,l,l,o, ,w,o,r,l,d`. There is no mimetype as you can see. What `Magic` library does - it tries to **guess** filetype by the contents of the file. Kind of like anti-virus software looks for patterns of viruses, these kinds of libraries try to **guess** the mimetype by some specific patterns common for those mimetypes.

Comment: I guess you are right :) Maybe I need to save additional column in my DB for file extension.

Comment: Your question is meaningless. Byte arrays are not files and do not have file extensions.

Comment: @EJP The question is not meaningless. Clearly he is referring to the contents of the byte array. Please be considerate with your postings and use discretion before publicizing your ignorance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If this is for storing a file that is uploaded:

- create a column for the filename extension
- create a column for the mime type as sent by the browser

If you don't have the original file, and you only have bytes, you have a couple of good solutions.

If you're able to use a library, look at using mime-util to inspect the bytes:

http://technopaper.blogspot.com/2009/03/identifying-mime-using-mime-util.html

If you have to build your own byte detector, here are many of the most popular starting bytes:

```
"BC" => bitcode,
"BM" => bitmap,
"BZ" => bzip,
"MZ" => exe,
"SIMPLE"=> fits,
"GIF8" => gif,
"GKSM" => gks,
[0x01,0xDA].pack('c*') => iris_rgb,
[0xF1,0x00,0x40,0xBB].pack('c*') => itc,
[0xFF,0xD8].pack('c*') => jpeg,
"IIN1" => niff,
"MThd" => midi,
"%PDF" => pdf,
"VIEW" => pm,
[0x89].pack('c*') + "PNG" => png,
"%!" => postscript,
"Y" + [0xA6].pack('c*') + "j" + [0x95].pack('c*') => sun_rasterfile,
"MM*" + [0x00].pack('c*') => tiff,
"II*" + [0x00].pack('c*') => tiff,
"gimp xcf" => gimp_xcf,
"#FIG" => xfig,
"/* XPM */" => xpm,
[0x23,0x21].pack('c*') => shebang,
[0x1F,0x9D].pack('c*') => compress,
[0x1F,0x8B].pack('c*') => gzip,
"PK" + [0x03,0x04].pack('c*') => pkzip,
"MZ" => dos_os2_windows_executable,
".ELF" => unix_elf,
[0x99,0x00].pack('c*') => pgp_public_ring,
[0x95,0x01].pack('c*') => pgp_security_ring,
[0x95,0x00].pack('c*') => pgp_security_ring,
[0xA6,0x00].pack('c*') => pgp_encrypted_data,
[0xD0,0xCF,0x11,0xE0].pack('c*') => docfile
```

Answer (score 57):

It turned out that there is a decent method in `JDK`'s `URLConnection` class, please refer to the following answer: [Getting A File's Mime Type In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java#847849)

If one needs to extract file extension from byte array instead of file, one should simply use `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream` (class to read bytes specifically from byte arrays) instead of `java.io.FileInputStream` (class to read bytes specifically from files) like in the following example:

```
byte[] content = ;
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
 //...close stream
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Only helpful if you can write the byte array content to a file then read that back again, which wasn't part of the original question. (I'm in the same situation.)

Comment: No-no, this solution works with any stream of bytes - please refer again to my edited answer. In Java, `InputStream` is an abstraction over `anything from where bytes can be read`, so when somewhere `InputStream` is needed - it's just a matter of finding correct `InputStream` implementation.

Comment: @SachinHR please elaborate your case and I'll try to help you

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe I need to save additional column in my DB for file extension.

That is a better solution than attempting to deduce a mimetype based on the database content, for (at least) the following reasons:

- If you have a mime type from the document source, you can store and use that.
- You could (potentially) ask the user to specify a mimetype when they lodge the document.
- If you *have to* use some heuristic-based scheme for figuring out a mimetype:

  - you can do the work once before creating the table row, rather than N times after extracting it, and
  - you can report cases where the heuristic gives no good answer, and maybe ask the user to say what the file type really is.

(I'm making some assumptions that may not be warranted, but the question doesn't give any clues on how the larger system is intended to work.)