# JetS3t update content\mime type

Tags: java, amazon-s3, mime-types, content-type, jets3t

Due to the problem [depicted here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=294542), I wish to update the content\mime type of already uploaded files. I am using [JetS3t](http://www.jets3t.org/) 0.9.0 to retrieve the object of interest, the I use [Getting A File's Mime Type In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java) to update the update the content\mime type, but I have no clue how to commit it on the object themselves, i.e. how to reflect it to the S3 storage.

Enclosed a snippet code, any help will be appreciated.

```
final String bucketName = "myBucketName";
final S3Bucket s3Bucket = s3Service.getBucket(bucketName);
final S3Object[] objects = s3Service.listObjects(bucketName);
String contentType = null;
for (S3Object object : objects) {
    contentType = MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(object.getName());
    object.setContentType(contentType);
    //how to commit the changes?
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the object by using [copyVersionedObject](http://www.jets3t.org/api/org/jets3t/service/S3Service.html#copyVersionedObject%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.jets3t.service.model.S3Object,boolean%29) to update it's metadata.
By using the same source and destination key only the metadata are updated.