# How to prevent QtWebkit load images?

Tags: qt, webkit, pyqt, qtwebkit

I don't need images in the page loaded in `QWebView`. With a minimum example, how do I do it?:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWebKit.QWebView()
    url = QtCore.QUrl("http://www.google.com")
    w.load(url)
    w.show()
```

I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524580/disable-automatic-image-loading-in-webview). However QtWebkit seems not work that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I found [`QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html).

So, basically:

```
# before loading the url:
st=w.settings()
st.setAttribute(st.AutoLoadImages,False)
```

would do the trick.