# How to get an image type without knowing its file extension?

Tags: java

I need to know a file extension without having the file extension? Is this possible with the java IO API?

I'm getting the following exception while reading a JPG file:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported Image Type
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

When i try to open the image in a normal image viewer in Mac OS X or Windows, it works just fine.

Is there any chances the file was renamed to a different type and it's original type is different from the extension?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the mime type with this code.

```
String imageName = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\home\\Desktop\\P092870.jpg";
File input = new File(imageName);
System.out.println("System Type description of " + input.getName() + " is " + 
          FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemTypeDescription(input));
System.out.println("Mime Type of " + input.getName() + " is " +
          new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mime-util](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/) library. My sample code will get the mime type of the file.

```
    String imagePath = "filepath";
    File file = new File(imagePath);

    if (MimeUtil.getMimeDetector(MagicMimeMimeDetector.class.getName()) == null)  {
        MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector(MagicMimeMimeDetector.class.getName());
    }
    Collection<MimeType> mimeTypes = MimeUtil.getMimeTypes(file);
    for (MimeType mimeType : mimeTypes) {
        System.out.println(mimeType.getMediaType());
    }
```