# How can I get a mime-type description without an internet connection?

Tags: java

Is there a standard reference that I can use to get standard mime type descriptions within Java without having an internet connection?

I could create my own reference but then I would need to maintain it.

**NOTE** I am after the description when I already have the mime type, I'm not trying to find the mime type for a file.

e.g. If I have `application/xml` I want to find the friendly name, i.e. `XML Document`.

I repeat, the linked question has nothing to do with this question besides the fact that it relates to mime types, read this properly and reopen!

Comment: I think [this might be what you are looking for][1]...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java

Comment: No, that's not what I'm after, I'm after finding the mime-type description if I already have the mime type. i.e. "application/xml" should return "XML" or similar.

Comment: I wish people voting to close would read the question properly, the linked question is NOT the same, the only similarity is that it relates to mime types. Please reopen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As "friendly name" isn't standardized that's a bit tricky - it's subjective. Two candidates:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#List_of_common_media_types
- http://help.dottoro.com/lapuadlp.php

Obviously you'd have to parse HTML with both if you want to process that automatically. If I didn't totally misinterpret your requirements you could easily turn the 2nd resource into a simple properties file for offline usage.

Comment: That's what I'm after, I was hoping for an existing library to use to I didn't have to maintain. I do require offline use so will create my own reference. The reason I asked is there are many applications that do show mime type descriptions so thought there may be something existing.