# How to determine whether a file is an image, video or audio file

Tags: java, android, file

I am using the following code to get files from gallery. The file that i retrieve is either image file, video file or an audio file based on user selection.

Now i am displaying the file retrieve from the gallery inside a list view. But i am not able to distinguish that the file selected by the user is image file(i.e .jpg / .png) or its an video file or an audio file.

By getting the extension and checking it in the if else condition its possible i know. But i want to know its there any possible way of doing this

**Code used to get image from Gallery is**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, GET_VIDEO_AUDIO);    
                            fileTransferDialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 12):

Just check the MIME type of the file.
Have a look at this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13889946/1570662

This might help

```
private static String getMimeType(String fileUrl) {
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(fileUrl);
    return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
}
```

Comment: Ok by getting the mine type. problem is solve, But there are some issue. Like suppose in my device i have .mp4 file and .flv video file. Now for mp4 file the mine type return is video..but for flv file mine type always return null.

Comment: This is also works if tried with local file paths such as `"/sdcard/path/to/video.extension"`. The problem is if the local file contains space in its path, it always returns null

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html). By determining the MIME type of the file, you can assess what file you're dealing with. There's also [this one](https://github.com/arimus/jmimemagic), which can be used to determine the MIME type etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type of the file to recognize the whether a file type is photo or video.

```
        String ext = file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".") + 1);

            if (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")
                        || ext.equalsIgnoreCase("png")
                        || ext.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")) {
                  type = "photo";
            }
```

Comment: This method is inefficient because there are too many file extensions; it is almost impossible to cater for them all.