# how to retrieve bmp file type using mimetype

Tags: java, file-type

Ive got a following code for recognizing image types in Java from another post here on stackoverflow.

```
FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
String mimeType = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(path);
System.out.println(mimeType);
```

It works fine , for jpeg , gif or png.

But the output for **BMP picture is NULL**. Anyone help ? :)

Comment: Found [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java#comment27442076_6899179). Tried running your snippet with Java 6 and 8, and it worked on 8 but not 6.