# Is it possible to use the content-type of a file to determine its filetype in Java?

Tags: java, json, content-type, file-type

If so, how can I do that?

I'm trying to write a method that takes a content-type and returns whether it is a JSON file or not.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can use a content-type to guess what a filetype is.  However, you can never be sure.  Not the least because content-types often lie.

Comment: I think that's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function which takes in a content-type string from an HTTP request and returns TRUE if the content-type was a JSON type or FALSE if it wasn't.

```
public static boolean isJsonContentType(String contentType) {
    return (contentType.equals("application/json"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been switching around between Perl, PHP, Javascript, Java, Bash, and Objective-C so much that I didn't catch it. I appreciate the feedback.