# How to get content type of a file which has no extension?

Tags: java, mime-types, file-type

I have saved all types of file without extension.  When reading through Java code, how to get content type of file?

```
File file = "/admin/sun"
byte[] pdfByteArray = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
if (fileName.endsWith(".pdf")) {
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
} else {
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
}
response.getOutputStream().write(pdfByteArray);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

What is if the file extension .pdf or .jpeg it is working then without extension how to get content-type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Files.probeContentType(path)` in jdk7. Or detect the file type yourself, according to different file type specifications. Say pdf http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

Comment: I test that with some csv files (with extension), and method returns text/csv, but if I delete the extension from file's name, it doesn't work. It returns text/plain

Answer (score 1):

You better do not rely on extensions. Find the mime type of the file.

See this SO question: [Getting A File's Mime Type In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java)

You must read the mime type with [`Files.probeContentType(path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29).

More relevant information on [mime types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29)

Comment: This should have just been a close vote.

Comment: I wanted to make clear that he must rely on mime type and how to get to it. But I already vote for close

Comment: That would have been better as a comment then. One close vote, one comment - not just an "answer" which in itself doesn't really answer the question (until an edit), but just redirects...

Comment: yeah. i upvoted