# How to find the mime type of video files in java

Tags: java, video

I have an application, in that am uploading mp4 and flv video files. In case, if the user changed the extension of some other file as 'mp4'/'flv' means the file is uploaded and the video is not playing. How can I check the mime type of mp4/flv video files in java.

I am struggling with this please anyone can help me to complete this task.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Java 7, then you can make use of `Files.probeContentType(path)`.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
 public class MimeTypes {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          Path path;
          try {
             path = Paths.get("/etc");  
             System.out.println( path + " : " + Files.probeContentType(path) );

             path = Paths.get("/dev/null");  
             System.out.println( path + " : " + Files.probeContentType(path) );

             path = Paths.get("/var/log/syslog.2.gz");  
             System.out.println( path + " : " + Files.probeContentType(path) );

             path = Paths.get("/var/run/rpcbind.sock");  
             System.out.println( path + " : " + Files.probeContentType(path) );

             path = Paths.get("abc.mp4");  
             System.out.println( path + " : " + Files.probeContentType(path) );

             path = Paths.get("MimeTypes.java");  
             System.out.println( path + " : " + Files.probeContentType(path) );
          } catch (Exception x) {
          }
       }
    }
```

Output:

```
# java MimeTypes 
/etc : inode/directory
/dev/null : inode/chardevice
/var/log/syslog.2.gz : application/x-gzip
/var/run/rpcbind.sock : inode/socket
abc.mp4 : video/mp4
MimeTypes.java : text/x-java
```

Oracle documentation of `Files` is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29).

**Another option:** [Apache Tika](http://lucene.apache.org/tika/)

Apache Tika is a toolkit for detecting and extracting metadata and structured text content from various documents using existing parser libraries. Tika has a lot of dependencies ... almost 20 jars ! But it can do a lot more than detecting filetype. For example, you can parse a PDF or DOC to extract the text and the metadata very easily.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    FileInputStream is = null;
    try {
      File f = new File("C:/Temp/mime/abc.mp4");
      is = new FileInputStream(f);

      ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler();
      Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
      metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, f.getName());
      Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
      // OOXMLParser parser = new OOXMLParser();
      parser.parse(is, contenthandler, metadata);
      System.out.println("Mime: " + metadata.get(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE));
      System.out.println("Title: " + metadata.get(Metadata.TITLE));
      System.out.println("Author: " + metadata.get(Metadata.AUTHOR));
      System.out.println("content: " + contenthandler.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (is != null) is.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Tried the above code, but its returning null value.

Comment: It return proper output to me. Anyways, I have updated answer with another sure-shot option for determining mime types.

Comment: Again thanks a lot for your reply, is there any particular API i've to add for implementing the apache tika

Comment: You will get all the info at Getting Started with Apache Tika. https://tika.apache.org/0.7/gettingstarted.html Contact me if needed.

Comment: parser.parse(is, contenthandler, metadata);its showing error in this line as, The method parse(InputStream, ContentHandler, Metadata, ParseContext) in the type Parser is not applicable for the arguments (FileInputStream, BodyContentHandler, Metadata).

Comment: not yet.till working on this from morning.In the 4th argument ParseContext whatelse i have to give.Now am passing null in the the 4th argument.Its checking for flv file but for mp4 its showing this error org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: TIKA-198: Illegal IOException from org.apache.tika.parser.mp4.MP4Parser@1c5c8c8a

Comment: Are you using org.apache.tika.parser.Parser ?

Comment: You can download samples from Apache tika from http://www.rgagnon.com/examples/demo-tika-libs.zip

Comment: Yes, am using org.apache.tika.parser.Parser