# check if input stream is String, image, etc... without using the ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I have this input stream from socket and I want to check if the input stream that I just read is an string, int, image etc...

Currently I am using DataInputStream..

Is there a way to check the type through byte or something else??

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java/8973468#8973468 is not exactly the same as you are asking, but it can help you, maybe you can write in a Temp file the first 1024 bytes as a sample and then use the accepted answer of such question.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you prepend each data item with a type tag.

Comment: is DataInputStream fast than ObjectInputStream??? Because I will consider using the ObjectInputStrean it if it is faster..

Comment: Define 'fast'. The limiting factor is the network, not the class. Serialization has its overheads but if you need it you need it.