# Spring MVC - setting the content type of a byte[] @ResponseBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am using Spring MVC 3.2.2.RELEASE, and this is my first attempt at using Spring's Java based configuration (`@Configuration`).

I have a controller that I use to handle certain files. The content of the files is read by my service method `MyContentService.getResource(String)`. At the moment, the content type is always `text/html`.

**How can I config my Spring MVC application so that it correctly sets the type of the content returned?** The content type can only be determined at runtime.

My controller at the moment, which incorrectly always sets the type to `text/html`:

```
@Controller
public class MyContentController {

    MyContentService contentService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "content/{contentId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] index(@PathVariable String contentId) {
        return contentService.getResource(contentId);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The following method works (with PNG and JPEG files), but I am not comfortable with `URLConnection` determining the content type (e.g. PDF, SWF, etc):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "content/{contentId}/{filename}.{ext}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> index2(@PathVariable String contentId, @PathVariable String filename, @PathVariable String ext, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = contentService.getResource(contentId);

    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(filename + "." + ext);
    if (mimeType != null) {
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(mimeType));
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(bytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        logger.warn("Unable to determine the mimeType for " + getRequestedUrl(request));
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Comment: Return a `ResponseEntity` or `HttpEntity` and set the content type.

Comment: You may try the `produces` attribute, which sets the `Content-Type` header of the response to the provided value, e.g.: `@RequestMapping(value = "content/{contentId}", produces = "application/octet-stream")`.

Comment: You may add `consumes` and `produces` to your `RequestMapping`.

Comment: @sp00m & @TJ: The problem with setting the `produces` attribute is that I do not know the type of file being requested. It could be an image, MP4, PDF, whatever, etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have got `ResponseEntity` working (see my edit), but I am not sure how reliable `URLConnection.guessContentFromName()` is.

Comment: You might want to use the `javax.activitation.FileTypeMap` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum Please submit `FileTypeMap` as an answer. It appears to handle far more types than `URLConnection`.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are only returning a `byte[]` which doesn't hold much information, only the actual content (as a `byte[]`).

You can wrap the `byte[]` in a `HttpEntity` or `ResponseEntity` and set the appropriate content type on that. Spring MVC will use the content type of the entity to set the actual content type to the response.

To determine the filetype you can use the `FileTypeMap` of the `javax.activation` framework or use a library (see [Getting A File's Mime Type In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java)).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "content/{contentId}")
@ResponseBody
public HttpEntity index(@PathVariable String contentId) {
    String filepath = // get path to file somehow
    String contentType = FileTypeMap.getDefaultFileTypeMap().getContentType(filePath);
    byte[] content = contentService.getResource(contentId);
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(mimeType));
    return new HttpEntity(content, headers);
}
```