# Print type of file in java

Tags: java, file-type

How do I print the type of a file in java?

I am able to print the length, whether it is readable or writable, but can you suggest a way to print the type of file?

Is there any built in method to find the type of file?

Comment: What do you mean by "type of file"?

Comment: Btw, have a look here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need **mime type** of the file you can use [Files.probeContentType(path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29) if you use `Java 7`.

Or If you need **File Extension**

**Method 1**:

You can use this to get the extension.

```
File file = new File("C:"/java.txt");
String fileName = file.getName();
if(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") != -1 && fileName.lastIndexOf(".") != 0)
System.out.println(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")+1));
```

**Method 2**:

You can use [FilenameUtils.getExtension(String filename)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29) from `Apache Commons IO`

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
File file=new File("E:/one.txt");
System.out.println(file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf('.'), file.getName().length()));
```

**output :**

```
.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    File file = new File("D:\\Storage\\example.js");
    String[] splitStrings = file.getName().split("\\.");
    String extension = splitStrings[splitStrings.length-1];
    System.out.println(extension); //prints js
```

Comment: An explanation of what you are doing here would be a good idea.

Comment: @RobBaillie oh. I'm just loading a file, slicing it up along `.` characters then take the last of the splitted string array and that's the extension.