# Java how to manually change MIME type of a file

Tags: java

I have a .m4a file that needs to be of mime type "audio/mp4" currently it is "video/mp4".

When I execute "file Rooo.m4a -i"

> Rooo.m4a: video/mp4; charset=binary

Is it possible to change it manually at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose (from command `file Rooo.m4a -i`) that you're using some linux OS. Java uses normal linux configuration where file types are guessed by `/etc/mime.types` and `$HOME/.mime.types`. Are you really sure you need to change it at runtime? Possible solution is to change system mime.types; [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes) can be useful in it.

If you're sure you probably need to check documentation for [`Files.probeContentType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path-) method. It states that you need to define your own FileTypeDetector subclasses and list them in `META-INF/services`.

> File type detectors are typically installed by placing them in a JAR
>   file on the application class path or in the extension directory, the
>   JAR file contains a provider-configuration file named
>   java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector in the resource directory
>   META-INF/services, and the file lists one or more fully-qualified
>   names of concrete subclass of FileTypeDetector  that have a zero
>   argument constructor.

Defining you own `FileTypeDetector` should solve the problem because it checks file type before the default one does.

See also: [Getting A File's Mime Type In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java?rq=1)