# Android: define image type (jpeg or jpeg2000) from inputstream

Tags: java, android, jpeg, inputstream, jpeg2000

I have an inputstream that contains image. Image can be as in `jpeg`, so in `jpeg2000` format. 
I've logged that stream and see next for `jpeg2000`:

```
������jP
```

for `jpeg` that it something like

```
������JFIF
```

To my understanding, there should be some magic bytes in stream, that will return image type. Any ideas how to get them? That should be compatible for Android

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java

Comment: any chances to do that on Android? `Files` class is not available there. Will rename title of question as well to point to android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static ImageType getImageType(byte[] data) {
    if (data == null) {
        return UNKNOWN;
    }
    byte[] header = new byte[11];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, header, 0, Math.min(data.length, header.length));
    int c1 = header[0] & 0xff;
    int c2 = header[1] & 0xff;
    int c3 = header[2] & 0xff;
    int c4 = header[3] & 0xff;
    int c5 = header[4] & 0xff;
    int c6 = header[5] & 0xff;
    int c7 = header[6] & 0xff;
    int c8 = header[7] & 0xff;
    int c9 = header[8] & 0xff;
    int c10 = header[9] & 0xff;
    int c11 = header[10] & 0xff;

    Log.d(TAG, "Headers: " + "\nc1: " + c1 + "\nc2: " + c2 + "\nc3: " + c3 + "\nc4: " + c4 +  "\nc5: " + c5
            + "\nc6: " + c6 + "\nc7: " + c7 + "\nc8: " + c8 + "\nc9: " + c9 + "\nc10: " + c10 + "\nc11: " + c11);

    // verify JPEG format
    if (c1 == 0xFF && c2 == 0xD8 && c3 == 0xFF) {
        if (c4 == 0xE0) {
            return JPEG;
        }

        /**
         * File format used by digital cameras to store images. Exif Format can be read by any application supporting JPEG. Exif Spec can be found at:
         * http://www.pima.net/standards/it10/PIMA15740/Exif_2-1.PDF
         */
        if ((c4 == 0xE1) && (c7 == 'E' && c8 == 'x' && c9 == 'i' && c10 == 'f' && c11 == 0)) {
            return JPEG;
        }
    }
    // verify JPEG2000 format. Codestream - http://sourceforge.net/p/optipng/mercurial/ci/a9d8ace0ee2f1aab641b787d252c166373bdeddc/tree/src/pngxtern/pngxrjpg.c#l26
    // 00 00 00 0C 6A 50 20 20 0D 0A 87 0A
    else if (c1 == 0x00 && c2 == 0x00 && c3 == 0x00 && c4 == 0x0C) {
        return JPEG2000;
    }

    // return JPEG by default
    return JPEG;
}
```

Some code snippet was taken from [here](https://github.com/Servoy/servoy-client/blob/e7f5bce3c3dc0f0eb1cd240fce48c75143a25432/servoy_shared/src/com/servoy/j2db/util/MimeTypes.java#L34) and enhanced for `JPEG2000` definition. 
By default returning JPEG format in my case, can be anything else in yours.
`UNKNOWN`, `JPEG` and `JPEG2000` are just my custom enums.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you want is to read some meta-data in order to find out more about the picture that you are loading.

I do not know of a API's existance in android in order to perform this operation, but [this](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) is probably what you need.

For example, in your case you could refer to [this](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/wiki/GettingStarted#from-a-stream) on the official documentation.

Comment: this one looks good, but it does not support `JPEG2000`. If type was not defined I can assume it to be JPEG2000, but looking for more handsome solution. Found few open sourced variants, trying to combine them right now

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check the type of file

```
private static String getMimeType(String fileUrl) {
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(fileUrl);
    return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
}
```