# how to know actual file type in java

Tags: java, file-extension

I have file for example 5555.33 but in fact file is arj archive file

```
String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension("C:\\5555.33");
```

the Extension returns 33 file. How to get actual file type arj from this file

Comment: The extension isn't `arj` it's `33`. If the extension were `arj`, the file would be named `5555.arj`.

Comment: The extension is no longer `arj`. You can try getting the mime-type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARJ archive files start with 0x60, 0xEA bytes. Just read the first two bytes to determine whether file is ARJ archive or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want the content after '.' . For this you can try

```
String str = "abc.txt";
System.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".")+1));
```

You can use

```
Files.probeContentType(path)
```

to know what type of file it is refered to

Comment: It's already stated, that he does NOT want the actual extension (the thingy that's now behind the "."), but the ?old? or maybe just the mime-type (which is already answered in another question)