# why does Conversion of Bytearray to MIME type returns NULL

Tags: java

Unable to get the MIME TYPE from bytearray - returns NULL for any MIME TYPE document.

```
    byte[] res ={-2,-1,0,114,0,101,0,115,0,117,0,108,0,116,0,13,0,10,0,73,0,32,0,108,0,111,0,118,0,101,0,32,0,73,0,110,0,100,0,105,0,97,0,43,0,52,0,51};
InputStream isr = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(res));
String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(isr);
System.out.println(mimeType);
```

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the source ([JDK 7](https://web.archive.org/web/20180608082054mp_/http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/net/URLConnection.java/#URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream%28java.io.InputStream%29), [JDK 11](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/da75f3c4ad5bdf25167a3ed80e51f567ab3dbd01/src/java.base/share/classes/java/net/URLConnection.java#L1488)), `guessContentTypeFromStream` only supports a very limited amount of mime types by inspecting the first 16 bytes:

- application/java-vm
- application/x-java-serialized-object
- text/html
- application/xml (UTF-8, UTF-8 w/ BOM, UTF-16 LE/BE, UTF-32 LE/BE)
- image/gif
- image/x-bitmap
- image/x-pixmap
- image/png
- image/jpg
- image/vnd.fpx
- audio/basic (.au LE/BE)
- audio/x-wav

`null` is returned as "text/plain" is none of them. If you need to guess another mime type you have to use another library.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way we can get MIME type from byte array?

Comment: Thanks...any java in-built libraries available to take care of other MIME types

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java (link provided by Stephen C in his answer) should get you started

Answer (score 1):

Because it cannot figure out what the content type actually is.  The javadocs say that `null` is returned if a content type cannot be determined.

If you want something better, you could start by looking at the Answers and Comments for this Question: [Getting A File's Mime Type In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java).