# Get MIME type from android resource?

Tags: android, mime-types, android-resources

How can I get MIME type from android resource URI ?

The URI look like:

```
android.resource://com.package.name/drawable/resourceName
```

I tried

```
ContentResolver cR = context.getContentResolver();
MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
mimetype = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
```

But returned MIME type is null

And

```
String url = uri.toString();
String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
mimetype = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
```

but there is no extension ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java  may help

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work