# mime type detection in Java

Tags: java, mime-types

Currently, I am detecting text/html or text/plain mime types by doing hack, which notices results that begin with and end with and make them html results. But now I also want to detect latex mime type and this hack is npt working anymore, but I cannot figure out the better way to create mime types. Here is my current code:

```
    private void method(String code) {
    HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
    if(code != null){
          boolean resultHtml = code.startsWith("<html>") && code.endsWith("</html>");
          map3.put(resultHtml ? "text/html" : "text/plain", code);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you are reading the content from a file then consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java

Comment: Use apache Tika https://tika.apache.org/1.14/detection.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat no I am not reading a file, I am receiving code as a string.

Comment: @YohannesGebremariam I have tried Tika. It can detect Html, but it is reading others as text/plain `String contentType = new Tika().detect(code.getBytes());`

Comment: You should also consider the case of `code`

Comment: @ScaryWombat where can I find that case?

Comment: @YohannesGebremariam and also Tika has a lot of dependencies, almost 20 jars

Comment: For LaTeX files you could try using Tika to find plaintext files (LaTeX files are plain text files containing markup commands) and then search for identifying LaTeX commands. `\begin{document}` would be a good choice.